# background заливает не весь экран

Tags: html, css

css :

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #bad6c0) no-repeat;
```

Так вот, если сайт умещается в пол экрана, градиентный фон тоже заливает пол экрана, а остальная половина БЕЛАЯ. Как залить весь экран, независимо от содержимого страницы???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, решено -

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dfffe8 100px, #97c49a 300px) no-repeat, #97c49a ;
```

Comment: Вы решили, сделав двойной фон - цвет и градиент? Попробуйте заменить цвета на другие, чтобы понять, что делает эта строчка :)

Попробуйте заменить в этой строчке `100px` и `300px` на `0`и `100%` соответственно и посмотрите результат.

Comment: Только что проверил, все ок. Пустое оставшееся пространство браузер нормально заливает необходимым цветом

Answer (score 0):

К какому элементу применяете? Проверьте, точно ли это body.

Comment: Клянусь, что это body. Проверил во всех браузерах. Если не использовать градиент, то нормально - заливает весь экран. Пришлось применить костыль - прописал в body { min-height: 1000px}, но это же не выход из положения?